# Inserting Records of an object using Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I am very new in apex and i am writing a simple insertion of records of an object using apex. I am getting an error of **Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List**

HERE IS MY CODE

```
  public static List<Ticket__c> CheckInAnonymous(String Event,String Firstname,String Lastname,String Email){

    List<Ticket__c> status = CreateAnonymousTicket(Event,Firstname,Lastname,Email); 

    // if(status.isEmpty())
    // {
    Datetime myDateTime = Datetime.now();
    String formattedDt = myDateTime.format('dd-MM-yyy hh:mm:ss');
    Ticket_log__c obj = new Ticket_log__c();

    obj.Check_In__c = formattedDt;
    obj.Event__c = status.Event__c; <--------- ERROR POINTS HERE
    obj.Status__c = 'IN';
    obj.Ticket__c = status.id;<--------- ERROR POINTS HERE                
    insert obj;
    //}
    return AET(Event);
}
```

Comment: `status` is a `List` of `Ticket` records not a single `Ticket`, hence your error.

Comment: Yeah will you please give me some code sample solve this problem ? i dont know the syntax.

Comment: `CreateAnonymousTicket` sounds like it should only be creating a single `Ticket`. You could change the method so that it only returns a `Ticket` rather than a `List` of them or if `status` will always contain at least 1 `Ticket` you could also do something like `status[0].Event__c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the values for look-up fields, you need to use the related object's id. Your variable `status` is a list, and therefore you can't get the Id from it, since it is a collection and not a single object. If you know that the list only has one object in it, you can get the id from it like so:

```
  public static List<Ticket__c> CheckInAnonymous(String Event,String Firstname,String Lastname,String Email){

    List<Ticket__c> status = CreateAnonymousTicket(Event,Firstname,Lastname,Email); 

    // if(status.isEmpty())
    // {
    Datetime myDateTime = Datetime.now();
    String formattedDt = myDateTime.format('dd-MM-yyy hh:mm:ss');
    Ticket_log__c obj = new Ticket_log__c();

    obj.Check_In__c = formattedDt;
    obj.Event__c = status[0].Event__c;
    obj.Status__c = 'IN';
    obj.Ticket__c = status[0].id;                
    insert obj;
    //}
    return AET(Event);
}
```

Comment: still got an error martin

Comment: @DanrylTigolCarpio This should work if there is at least one ticket in the `status` variable.